# Python (AutoKey) loop surprisingly has no result

Tags: python, autokey

While i try to find out if window is closed in (Linux) wine my python loop has a strange and (for me) logical behavior.

the source with this loop beginning (Source 1):

```
for x in range(0, 290): # default is 25
    keyboard.send_keys("\n#40 x='%s'" % str(x))
    keyboard.send_keys("")
    if x > 1:
        keyboard.send_keys("\n#42 x='%s'" % str(x))
        break
```

For me it gives the following logical output (output 1):

```
#40 x='1'
#40 x='2'
#42 x='2'
```

**But** the source with this loop beginning (Source 2):

```
for x in range(0, 290): # default is 25
    # keyboard.send_keys("\n#40 x='%s'" % str(x))
    keyboard.send_keys("")
    if x > 1:
        keyboard.send_keys("\n#42 x='%s'" % str(x))
        break
```

**gives me no output at all**

**expected output for (Source 2)**:

```
#40 x='2'
#42 x='2'
```

i testing with this file https://gist.github.com/sl5net/b10770763d49b30fe2105b365ab3421e
inside AutoKey i Linux Mint. Its starting an AutoHotKey Script (https://lintalist.github.io/).

if you want seeing me (i spreche deutsch im live stream), i struggling with this problem, look here to this live stream: https://youtu.be/V6kQAgiyj1Y?t=571

Comment: Source 1 and 2 are identical. Am I missing something?

Comment: it runs https://github.com/sl5net/Lintalist4Linux-version-0.00000001-Alpha/blob/master/test.sh and this test.sh starts https://github.com/sl5net/Lintalist4Linux-version-0.00000001-Alpha/blob/master/sendF1v2.ahk that runs lintalist.ahk

Comment: I couldn't find an explanation for this phenomenon. BTW I am only interested in the phenomenon academically. It was only part of a larger problem that I have now solved - here: https://gist.github.com/sl5net/f68d302f0f5a40d05e6a2e182b453a51

Comment: Don't know, but when anything weird like this happens, the first thing to try is to `import time` and add `time.sleep(0.1)` calls everywhere and see if it helps. If it does, you can pull them out gradually or change the delay times. AutoKey types way faster than you do and many applications can't keep up. The next thing to try is running a trace to see what AutoKey thinks is going on. See https://github.com/autokey/autokey-python2/wiki/Problem-Reporting-Guide